# Cannot SSH log into docker created by minikube with Hyper-V driver

Tags: minikube

I have installed minikube and did successfully create a cluster with `minikube start --driver=hyperv`, perhaps. I deduce that it is successfully created because after `minikube status` I got output that all is running and configured.

The next step I do is to `ssh docker@IP_ADDRESS` while `IP_ADDRESS` is the one I got from `minikube ip` command.

The result is that I am prompted for the password. I type `tcuser` but it seems that password is incorrect.

Where to look for now? Is password wrong or maybe something is not set up properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the SSH private key on Minikube (already created), no need for password:

```
ssh -i $(minikube ssh-key) docker@$(minikube ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated [`minikube ssh`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/ssh/) command that just does this.

Note that this command directly logs into the Kubernetes Node that Minikube creates.  You should need this rarely, if ever.  (I am currently principally using Minikube in my day job even for routine Docker tasks, and don't need `minikube ssh`.)  `minikube start` sets up your host Kubernetes configuration so that `kubectl` commands can access the single-node cluster, without needing the `ssh` step.